# Hive Query Performance for Windowing on Large Dataset

Tags: performance, optimization, hive, hiveql, hdp

I have dataset like this A person identified by an ID, use some object identified by another ID and amount of time he use that. I want to know the first 20 items highly used by the person. Amount of data is very large over 100 million and each id can produce about 200 object he may use.

So first thing i created a projection table with cluster and keep the things sorted how the things will happen in the mapper so that all the things will be at one place in the node so that mapper when it is distributing will find the things locally

```
CREATE TABLE person_objectid_dwell ( person string, objectid string, sum_dwell bigint)
CLUSTERED BY (person) SORTED BY (sum_dwell desc,objectid asc)INTO 100 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC;
```

And once done i inserted the data from the feeder table like this

```
insert into person_objectid_dwell  select person, objectid, sum_dwell from person_objectid_dwell distribute by person sort by sum_dwell desc, objectid asc;
```

And then query using windowing with a table creation

```
create table person_top20_objectsdwell as select * from ( select person, objectid, sum_dwell, 
rank() over (partition by person order by sum_dwell  desc ) as rank
from person_objectid_dwell ) t where rank <21;
```

Problem is this i am not getting the performance what i think i should get, i set the number of reducers etc. Program is running with 3000+ mapper and 1000+ reducers and mapping phase is not getting over at all.

Comment: Check what mappers are doing in their logs, maybe there is something unusual or some bottleneck

Comment: I removed partition column skewedness because some of the rows were having unwanted data so it went down little bit but still things are not there yet.

Comment: The question remains the same: what mappers are doing in their logs, maybe there is something unusual or some bottleneck